# TypeScript merge generic array

Tags: typescript

I want generic object array to one object.

But, It generate union type.

How can I get one merged object type? like `{key: string; boo?: string; foo?: string;}`

```
type PluginType<T extends Record<string, unknown> = {}> = T & {
  key: string;
}

function renderer<T extends Record<string, unknown> = {}>(plugins?: Array<PluginType<T>>) {
  const test = {} as T;

  return () => test;
}

// ---cut---

const plugins1: PluginType<{boo?: string}> = { key: '', boo: '' };
const plugins2: PluginType<{foo?: string}> = { key: '', foo: '' };

const render = renderer([plugins1, plugins2]);
render().boo
render().foo
```

[typescript playgound link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgVwOYEsB2AVcEA8GoQAewEaAJgM5QBKEAxgPYBOZOFwT6SANFAmgGs0DAO5oAfFAC8UAN4BfSTPwAyOQCgoUARBAAuKO05okAbnXz16gGb86wFAzRQmpMhFdM8BYm6q1GFjYOLl5+IVEJaTlFAAowRFQ0CgB+AwBBJiYAQxAceGR0LEg8cXEASg0tRmTgKBJ2aIUobKoMc00XCGAEJmdYyqlJBuBzS3UAegmoAFo5ugRgOZmrGsaEwuSARgMCpOLcWQAjBgY0wxCTRSbtXQMAcnveE4YH+6h5czW6jaSKACZdokitgcLJrKdzkYuNcZLJbvooI9eBDXkj3p9Vk5Gq5yB5orj3J5YgBtX7oChbXjk5L-AC65XMhI8AwAdC91MymGzUUA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJX0lN) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (If you reply, please mention @jcalz to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz That's the way I wanted it. Can you write a description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a value `v` of type `V` and a value `w` of type `W`, then the array `[v, w]` is the type `Array<V | W>`, where the element type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) (since each element is either a `V` or a `W`); it is not of type `Array<V & W>` where the element type is an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) (which would imply that each element is *both* a `V` *and* a `W`, which is untrue).  So you can't just infer the element type from an array and then use it as the merged thing directly.

Instead, what you want to do is to interpret the type of `plugins` as a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) so the compiler knows the type of each element separately, and then use some type magic to combine the elements of the tuple type into a single type via intersection.  Here's one way:

```
type TupleToIntersection<T extends any[]> = {
  [I in keyof T]: (x: T[I]) => void }[number] extends
  (x: infer I) => void ? I : never;

declare function
  renderer<T extends PluginType<Record<string, unknown>>[]>(
    plugins?: [...T]):
  () => TupleToIntersection<T>;
```

So `renderer()` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T`, the type of `plugins`.  Note that I've marked `plugins` as having type `[...T]` instead of `T`.  That's [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) syntax, and it is just there to give the compiler a hint that it should interpret `plugins` as being a tuple and not an unordered array.

Once we have `T`, we compute `TupleToIntersection<T>` to be the intersection of the element types of `T`.  (So if `T` is `[V, W, X, Y]`, then `TupleToIntersection<T>` is `V & W & X & Y`.)  This is done by using [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) and [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types).  It's similar to how [the `UnionToIntersection<T>` type works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50374908/2887218): I take each element of the tuple and map it to a function parameter type (`[V, W, X, Y]` becomes `[(x: V)=>void, (x: W)=>void, (x: X)=>void, (y: Y=>void)]`), which is a [contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Contravariant_method_parameter_type) position.  Then I merge that into a union of functions (`((x: V) => void)|((x: W) => void)|((x: X) => void)|((x: Y) => void)`), and from there, infer a single function parameter type that matches it.  A union of functions accepts an intersection of parameters, by contravariance, and so the compiler infers `(x: infer I) => void` (where `I` in the example would become `V & W & X & Y`).  If that's too confusing then... uh, it's magic ‍♂️✨‍♀️.

---

Anyway, let's test it:

```
const plugins1: PluginType<{ boo?: string }> = { key: '', boo: '' };
const plugins2: PluginType<{ foo?: string }> = { key: '', foo: '' };

const render = renderer([plugins1, plugins2]);
/* const render: () => {
    boo?: string | undefined;
} & {
    key: string 
} & {
    foo?: string | undefined;
}  */

render().boo // string | undefined
render().foo // string | undefined
```

Looks good!  The returned value is a function that returns an intersection of the two element types, and thus `render()` is known to have a `boo` and a `foo` property, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgVwOYEsB2AVcEA8GoQAewEaAJgM5QBKEAxgPYBOZOFwT6SANFAmgGs0DAO5oAfOKgBeKPgBkUAN5QBEEAC4o7TmiQBuKAF8AUCdCQ5CMHAgYGASTQkmFesBQM0eAsVKUoAEM0EABtAF0pWSUTKChQhyh0VXUGADM5cK0ACkItDATwgEoZKQA3BhQyY1C0BABbACMIJnDfEnIKWKhcrXQ0lqgHEulyyuqAfiGoLTQIMpb9MzJ6OECmaDT+Og8vbo3yFpafIg6A+GR0LEgcWkYWNg4uXn4hUQlxCPFs7ribS7QFAmWlCADpwRhihputkRlIMNZbPYnC43DtPN4MOIliZGIDgFB-qhAQBGLQXYnXXAqRoMBjA7RPPTGKLKFKaKAAck5vFpDC03OMSzx7EJiGJFAATOTxVdsDgVGk6QydFwWTI2WoOdzeEr+VzOUKzCKCQcVkwNWajkxsqEiegKCTePbAZLiksAPQAKigJqgVqYOThyl+UD5KqZSCgAB8+Ic0ugIGQlkYoIoYnE4lqtKrmSZU+nQ3qI7oo7H+CsE3Nk-m4l6PWYA7DQXyoB6PYzSzG45XE2QTE2iqC9W2O7myz2IFWk0A)

Comment: I posted a question on a slightly different issue.
Can you please check this too?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74217585/how-to-merge-of-many-generic-in-typescript