# How to merge of many generic in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

```
type PluginType<
  Meta extends Record<string, unknown> = {},
  Field extends Record<string, unknown> = {}
> = {
  key: string;
  getMeta?(meta: Meta): void
  getField?(meta: Field): void
};
```

I want to return merged `Meta` and `Field` of `PluginType` to `render` function.

The `render` function takes `PluginType[]` as an argument.

```
declare function render<
  T extends PluginType[] // Is this ok?
>( options?: { plugins: T }): {
  meta:  // merge T.Meta
  field: // merge T.Field
};
```

```
const p1: PluginType<
  { metaBoo?: string },
  { fieldBoo?: string }
> = { key: 'p1' };

const plugins2: PluginType<
  { metaFoo?: string },
  { fieldFoo?: string }
> = { key: 'p2'};

const { meta, field } = render([p1, p2]);
```

In the above situation, I want the return value of `render` to come out like the one below.

```
{
  meta: { metaBoo?: string, metaFoo?: string },
  field: { fieldBoo?: string, fieldFoo?: string }
}
```

How can I specify the return type of the `render` function for this?

I posted a similar question yesterday and attached it. [TypeScript merge generic array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74202096/typescript-merge-generic-array)

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/ko/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgVwOYEsB2AVcEA8AoKKAWQmAEMoIAPYCNAEwGcoAlCAYwHsAnenR4N3RIANFARoA1mk4B3NAD4oAXigBvAL4iCUAGIoIcepRp0mrDjz4ChaUeKkz5S1Zrwv1OyRBAAuKDbCANw6SKQk5AD8ABQAtqRk-hFkAJT+AG6cKPShpPqG9DHx5P75RmlQmdl4GiF4ePQccGTc0ABmEuzAKJxoUK0MEK3c+IQYJrQMzPDI6FiQANoAuu7RUJxg3b2Mkf5qUGCIqGiM-gsAdJcYS1AaFfvFiQ7ScmhibQZG-hIv8rd1eAA9ICoABacHsBDAcGg+pcE7AA5HdCMACM-hmx3muAeCQAQpxOLsAoJhLcxPsPgUCUT-IE7LcPPtvH4oAByNn-PDwgRI2YnABMGORmGwOFx5F0hOJ9KQ5PUUCpRiltJJtjlGiZUBZ-g5tTh20RA0a3BU-TMQyG0TUOkO-NOUAWduOaLEzpRApWdzqxqG50ekX9+MJIV93CDUQjZBVoYt4aVhXOCZpscG8c+iYTMfqQA)

Comment: it is not clear for me why you are expecting `{ meta:... , field: ...}`

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnbYxN) what you're looking for?  If so I can write it up; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz Oh my god... Exactly what I was looking for. I couldn't have done it without you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want this:

```
declare function renderer<
  T extends PluginType[]
>(options?: { plugins: [...T] }): {
  meta?: TupleToIntersection<{ [I in keyof T]:
    T[I] extends PluginType<infer M, any> ? M : never
  }>,
  field?: TupleToIntersection<{ [I in keyof T]:
    T[I] extends PluginType<any, infer F> ? F : never
  }>
};

type TupleToIntersection<T extends any[]> = {
  [I in keyof T]: (x: T[I]) => void }[number] extends
  (x: infer I) => void ? I : never;
```

It is similar to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74202096/typescript-merge-generic-array) where [I defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74202280/2887218) `TupleToIntersection<T>` to take a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) like `[A, B, C, D]` and compute the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of its elements like `A & B & C & D`.

In this case you expect the output of `renderer({options: pluginTuple})` where `pluginTuple` is of tuple type `[PluginType<M1, F1>, PluginType<M2, F2>, PluginType<M3, F3>]` to be of type `{meta?: M1 & M2 & M3; field?: F1 & F2 & F3}`.  So before we use `TupleToIntersection`, we need to convert the type of `pluginTuple` to `[M1, M2, M3]` (for the `meta` property) and to `[F1, F2, F3]` (for the `field` property).

To do this we can make a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays); if you have a generic tuple type `T`, then the mapped type `{[I in keyof T]: ...T[I]...}` will also be a tuple type where each element `I` of the input tuple `T` is converted to some corresponding output element type.  And to convert `PluginType<M, F>` to either `M` or `F`, we can use [conditional type inference with `infer`].  Such as `{[I in keyof T]: T[I] extends PluginType<infer M, any> ? M : never}` or `{[I in keyof T]: T[I] extends PluginType<any, infer F> ? F : never}`

---

Let's test it out:

```
const plugins1: PluginType<{ metaBoo?: string }, { fieldBoo?: string }> = { key: '' };
const plugins2: PluginType<{ metaFoo?: string }, { fieldFoo?: string }> = { key: '' };

const render = renderer({
  plugins: [plugins1, plugins2]
});

/* const render: {
    meta?: ({
        metaBoo?: string | undefined;
    } & {
        metaFoo?: string | undefined;
    }) | undefined;
    field?: ({
        fieldBoo?: string | undefined;
    } & {
        fieldFoo?: string | undefined;
    }) | undefined;
} */
```

Looks good. `render` is an object type with an optional property `meta` of type `{metaBoo?: string} & {metaFoo?: string}`, and an optional property `field` of type `{fieldBoo?: string} & {fieldFoo?: string}`.

---

So there you go.  There are some caveats that this only works as well as conditional type inference can work.  If you explicitly annotate a type as `PluginsType<M, F>` then we can probably `infer` `M` and `F` from it.  But if you just write a value and expect the compiler to infer that it is of type `PluginsType<M, F>` then you might be disappointed.  I note that your `PluginType<M, F>` definition has `M` and `F` in optional properties, so they might not be present at all, and they are in a [contravariant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) position, so they might be inferred in a way you don't expect.  Dealing with either of these is outside the scope of the question as asked, but it's important to note that `infer` is not magic and has its limits.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgVwOYEsB2AVcEA8AoKKAWQmAEMoIAPYCNAEwGcoAlCAYwHsAnenR4N3RIANFARoA1mk4B3NAD4oAXigBvAL4iCUAGIoIcepRp0mrDjz4ChaUeKkz5S1Zrwv1OyRBAAuKDbCANw6SKQk5AD8ABQAtqRk-hFkAJT+AG6cKPShpPqG9DHx5P75RmlQmdl4GiF4eKCQUBgIYHAQGJwAkmi03IwcwCicaDgYJrQMzGRoIADaALoeajpzXVDoUN4gnABmzQv+0VT+GGsLKSpKVcYac2gIsQBGENwLE2aMOsf+6LuvUC6l2U1yyxkigKg-jQEHSrzq9A4cDI3Gguwk7CGIygqIYr1e+EI42ok3M8GQ6CwkEW7minDAWLQjEi-jUUDaFKZ-jmADo+Rh3hoKitCMUyCzmq12p0en0BpjhqM2WsNmgtj49gdfDoiecPlNYIhUJhsDg-gCiGIZiAlBCiFCoDC4dwdBoFNpCLsDEYJS02h1ur1XvLGThletNttNQLtYRdV13iTPobOVTcNaxObuHpbXoHU7Xq6FDU6ngAPRlqAAWhr7AQwBrVfqXCZwHZRvQjAAjP5yca02GoGKAEKcTgSwJ2KBadRQL0FUfj-yTpDT5bqvxQADkW+nIRbAnbnMYACZex2TZBB2LdGOJ4JhNOxGz50Zb0uAg+p26VLPtv4dz3ZsRkPXFEWzVQwPxbhohFI9jUYbkOQQrsxGQzsTwWGoUjqMsACooAPNsoO4VkdSHBIJVg8i4wo8hF3vWxVwAHwcREvRhegQlojQoAAMk8WjaJvO9ly-Fi2IgDiIC48ihSgViJHY9AZO4uNX0KI44KEudvXoBixKYhTJOk2SeP4wSdN0gp30Yx9FLxUy1MIeSHOUziQl4vCy3qEieTFSJ-ISRcQj8gKgvId9QrMV4eQ0wKNJCvA-PiuK9Ki+ogA)