# Extract types from array in function argument into a generic intersection type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to extract a generic type that is a union of the types of objects present in an array passed within the argument of a function. It's easiest to illustrate this with code, so given the following:

```
type Extension = {
  name: string,
  fields: {
    [key: string]: string
  }
}

type Config = {
  name: string,
  extensions: Extension[]
}

const ext1: Extension = {
  name: 'ext1',
  fields: {
    field1: 'test',
    field2: 'test'
  }
}

const ext2: Extension = {
  name: 'ext1',
  fields: {
    field3: 'test',
    field4: 'test'
  }
}

const config: Config = {
  name: 'Test',
  extensions: [ext1, ext2]
}

// Ignore the obviously wrong typings here
function create(config: Config): T { ... }
```

How can I ensure that T has the following type:

```
type CombinedFields = {
  field1: string,
  field2: string,
} & {
  field3: string,
  field4: string
}
```

Comment: Is it strictly required to declare `ext1` and `ext2` to be of type `Extension`? It looks like `field1`, `field2`, and so on only exist in the values `ext1` and `ext2`, but never in any types, and these values are already declared to be of type `Extension`, so there probably is no further type inference from the compiler either; to give the compiler a fighting chance, can this typing on `ext1` and `ext2` be dropped?

Comment: Yes -- in my actual use-case the types of the extensions varies and is further inferred through deeper generics down the chain. I think the side-effect is ultimately similar to what you're suggesting.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NnlRxW) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Holy cow @jcalz that works! :D I had to modify quite a bit to shim it into my actual implementation, but works like a charm. You rock -- thank you!!

Comment: Oops I have to go to bed so I hope to get back to this tomorrow (I forgot that the semiannual clock-fiddling is removing an hour from this weekend)

Comment: oh... fiddlesticks. guess I'm going to bed after 3am tonight  no worries; I'll keep an eye on this thread so I can approve your answer whenever you get it up. thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to be possible at all, you need the compiler to keep track of the particular keys and values of `ext1`, `ext2`, and `config`.  But if you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) those variables with wide types like `Extension` and `Config`, you will throw away the information you need to keep track of.  So you can't annotate.  Instead, you can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to *check* that the variables are assignable to those types without widening to them:

```
const ext1 = {
  name: 'ext1',
  fields: {
    field1: 'test',
    field2: 'test'
  }
} satisfies Extension;

/* const ext1: {
    name: string;
    fields: {
        field1: string;
        field2: string;
    };
} */

const ext2 = {
  name: 'ext1',
  fields: {
    field3: 'test',
    field4: 'test'
  }
} satisfies Extension;

/* const ext2: {
    name: string;
    fields: {
        field3: string;
        field4: string;
    };
} */
```

Okay, those types know about the field names.  For `config` we need to go a little further; it's important for `extensions` to keep track of the length and order of its elements, so it can distinguish between `[ext1, ext2]` and `[Math.random()<0.5 ? ext1 : ext2]` (or at least I'm assuming we need to distinguish between those).  That means we should use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on `config` and allow `Config`'s `extensions` property to be a [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) array type because that's what `const` assertions give you:

```
type Config = {
  name: string,
  extensions: readonly Extension[]
}
const config = {
  name: 'Test',
  extensions: [ext1, ext2]
} as const satisfies Config;

/* const config: {
    readonly name: "Test";
    readonly extensions: readonly [{
        name: string;
        fields: {
            field1: string;
            field2: string;
        };
    }, {
        name: string;
        fields: {
            field3: string;
            field4: string;
        };
    }];
} */
```

Okay, now that's enough information to proceed.

---

Here's one approach:

```
type ExtensionsToIntersection<T extends readonly Extension[]> =
  { [I in keyof T]: (x: T[I]["fields"]) => void }[number] extends
  (x: infer I) => void ? I : never;

declare function create<T extends Config>(config: T):
  ExtensionsToIntersection<T["extensions"]>;
```

The `ExtensionsToIntersection<T>` type takes a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of `Extension`-assignable elements and converts it to an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the `fields` properties of those elements.  The technique is very similar to that described in the answer to [TypeScript merge generic array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74202096/2887218).  In general, the idea is to map the things we want to intersect into a *contravariant* type position (in this case, the parameter of a function), and then infer a single type for the union of those (inferring from the parameter position of a union of functions results in an intersection of those parameter types, as described in [the release notes for conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types)).

Let's test it:

```
const ret = create(config);
/* const ret: {
    readonly field1: "test";
    readonly field2: "test";
} & {
    readonly field3: "test";
    readonly field4: "test";
} */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsCA7AzgSwPZKgXigbwCgookBDAWwgC4oVgAnNJAcwBpioAzNCAGwAmKWkRIkA2gGsIIWvSasAunMbMWnAL6EthAMZZ6UCAgCMuAp3JVaAcmPATNjiR78hIzi96CTtxPSdPbm8BACY-CADNbToyYDQUVxRYBGR0LABuQkIAegAqKH1UYCNTDzFSSho6VVYsitdBYQsKhpDfGoUWetavN3DOtR6SDSyNKDyc7KLDe1DzUUrrKDtTQL6m8rFGgQBmCIDnbZCAFgPgG2jxlDiEpJTEVEwkLNyCmZK5rZIravkhoI7ZqLXo7faDOpBNpuM4Q7pBUYxSbZUCQKAAYSwPBYC0sVRUXSO9jSz2aDAgZAEWD4IAeJKw4kU2j0BhKRWxuJ++JWABVIhciakngZaOJ7CY2KVgKEmeMyMkPrF4oleMlMUhsa98oVWTqNWgWN8oOTKdTab9aAAiPn0S3DY0UqlIGlS+moWgmp0u8Qg1oWuH26GbFq9Vo7Dr-SGhsMhAaR+HRxEVDSS30Vf3xwPHNzAqGhsEEgHRoMCWGZvMje0aRRjCZTQio6DwR7pVA8jAASSQiAYKAguniWAAPDzXUghA7Tc7ac23YyAHy4Tj4KDiDtQZhQaQgDBcKA85RQAAUcFoPLXinElqBlsUAEpcIuAG4YNACKAacRIACuFAARhADCKGOQicCetDMFwgFQB2D44M+r7vgA-DBUC0EgEBPoBrwCP2fBkOS3DfkgA7PIUJqICOIFqliBrzke7IGmed7UJws7Cm2nbdoBfakcO56WsSHEoLe86vIq5IlHgugURADG0Swd5ZNqEkQMARqemawRuB0lr+MAdpBJp07aYIAx6fyhnjAAZCGJDGS6BZQBZtr2g5tI7LCLkGbWkxAA)

Comment: Perfect answer and excellent explanation! I had some fun implementing this cause in my actual use-cases, extensions are classes, but with some handy usage of InstanceTypes, I was able to get it to work great.

Curious: is there any way to move the as cost satisfies operator to a helper function (e.g. createConfig)? I tried, but had no luck; seems the nested types are lost in the pipeline. Not a big deal cause I have boilerplate gen scripts, but ultimately I'd like for it to be a little more foolproof if possible.

Comment: @JonnyAsmar Use TS 5.0's `const` generics: https://tsplay.dev/mp08xm