# convert non-generic function to generic function with static types

Tags: typescript

To begin with, I have a tree of routes as follows:

```
interface RouteObject {
  id: string;
  path: string;
  children?: RouteObject[];
}

const routeObjects: RouteObject[] = [
  {
    id: 'root',
    path: '/',
    children: [
      {
        id: 'auth',
        path: 'auth',
        children: [
          {
            id: 'login',
            path: 'login',
            children: [
              {
                id: 'vishal',
                path: 'vishal',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            id: 'register',
            path: 'register',
          },
          {
            id: 'resetPassword',
            path: 'reset-password',
          },
          {
            id: 'resendConfirmation',
            path: 'resend-confirmation',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 'playground',
        path: 'playground',
        children: [
          {
            id: 'playgroundFormControls',
            path: 'form-controls',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I am trying to achieve a flat object of id vs path as follows:

```
{
  root: '/',
  auth: '/auth',
  login: '/auth/login',
  vishal: '/auth/login/vishal',
  register: '/auth/register',
  resetPassword: '/auth/reset-password',
  resendConfirmation: '/auth/resend-confirmation',
  playground: '/playground',
  playgroundFormControls: '/playground/form-controls'
}
```

Here is the Typescript code (without generics) that is capable of producing the output:

```
function createRoutes(routeObjects: RouteObject[], parentPath = '', routes: Record<string, string> = {}) {
  for (let { id, path: relativePath, children } of routeObjects) {
    let rootRelativePath =
      relativePath === '/' || parentPath === '/' ? `${parentPath}${relativePath}` : `${parentPath}/${relativePath}`;
    if (id) routes[id] = rootRelativePath;
    if (children) createRoutes(children, rootRelativePath, routes);
  }
  return routes;
}
```

Here is the link of Playground: [Working code without using Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsCukDyAjAKwgTGQG8AoZZYAEwH4AuZAZzClAHMBuK5ABzhgAFk1bsuvagmHAANrSgQQYjNgj4iJANoBdXgF8KFBOhBtkULLkLEwLZmptawe5AF5k2vpWrU6zADkVuhggQA0fNSCIkEA9BFRyDLyisrM3n5+vll+AciBcNjCibl+McJBRSKlZcmyCkogGUllOXV5tEFy6JygtR3RQpUFPX0gA4MpjelerYPtg1n5gQBuwCzCcHKTS0OxBeub27uDBpF7yLoXZzcdix0rSn1s0KdlFUHPG5BQ737neZZB51J4QFgQMAABTgLBYAHd0FBaP8sp8CkoIWAALSCOGI5Go5CApYgspgiEgWgAYTMMGAUAAtkJgGYifsRsFwcpaNjTCB6UyWWy7nUSXVrvNxcCgTQugV+HI4ABPThWTBU-7owKKlVqrCa0VZaZpZpzUmy5bynVK1XqqkAMSRjNp4CschY7IEwyCMGdfLM7HQHqJ0tykrKYYjxMi+mMMA1JFZIGSSiEECc4IAFOrnHYHGhrBpbDprt6mtDhh4ChFLEWC6hiEjaAAeNgcECccLiDucAB81bIBgAlOQ+H6oMgs3JIeQ5d30UolWBgKsIDCRN2TU1ich0DA6+pNPnR4sZ6QQmBG8vV+uq+55kuWWuN8IPO5PIEEsgAD4-8vKJWIjvp+370MgAAGAAkZCCBWr4GDBT4ri+wwGBByDMNBsFwPBaFxEhEA3qhIjoVIeQHlmdCjrm4LaHQujVpe17PneIjkf4lHbsoo4IGmkCZiwWbcSA3bMURrGvmJ9bDuRRjUEoYCYFAKa0SwhjGPyFhqdWfEQOmgk5kWx4kCwsmaWYLDBhAAB0YxGeoZkUEAA)

The above code produces correctly, but cannot produce static types. By static types, I mean, the return type of `createRoutes` should be an object with real ids and real paths, **not** just `Record<string, string>`.

So, I tried to use generics, but cannot go farther than this: [Generics non working playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATiArlApgeQEYCsXChGAXhgG0BYAKBhgG9LrqBLAEwC4YByBEKDgGnoMADgEMoAC3YcA9P0HVg4xgBtmcFGHbkqDanR26mbTiOTi5Bw6IlTTEi4YaKVajVvmPaHzzBZTlIADmjGAOPsJikpwBwaEClj7OquqapN7h%20uGefpwAbowQ4iLKYVm61lEc%20YXFpWUAvvFlMAC6TeGN6bqZZTlcKMHQKHB1PhVS6oOoI%200%20nQmGPVl96hAoUAAKIhAQAO4gcMyjnuOcq%20sAtKI7%204fHuvNZS%20ErKGtgzADC4ABmjHAAWzEjHA9yskQmbw0zAuoDAf0BwNBs08j08bXSaO6XV8xg4QmUIgAnoEEIgPmDTvjCSSyRSUbokq5UtonjjdH0CcTSUgPgAxA4A75gKAIZQQMHlCGcH6C2HgUUgcWSmBYwwYhZqjXUeYtGDbGBw6AAbkolCgRKEKBgACUkKhMDg8EQYAAKC1WkA-eD29DYXD4ACUJDAiABGGGLVNFHNlutAElmAAeAAqMBQAA9UB8CHbkH6nVAAHwulMkDgsDh6zPZ5gEaBwEKBGAAfhgZYrRz17DAKFyw2jHutWwkqfTWehud9joDJeIHYqVfHtfroqbrfb5cX3Zgvf7cEHcZgnyUqkTY5rk9t0-9eDnm44TJSS8vOev%20ZneBILUEbY7T40KsQzDCM4GrCc3zzB1bygDw-3LADQhaYDw0jctKx-Swez7YZBGw-dDytY9T2YEdxAvCC63faDC3vf8SOfcCV2ogsA2-X8H0QoDQ1QsDlyvKDWLwODOIYwDkJ40DkPxSIqw8fDcJ0BSDzNGMKCHY91DEFBBIgCjmMEz9ixdV0ADpzJEOBAggdgRDAIlv0DIgSx6EgAGlfDAGBzxTIsWnYMjUyLaMdRgAAyLxLBIAApTziJcHy-PYE8XEC3zo3qaNYyI3T9IEm9aJdG11kQOAwBTOMk0%20LTUFy3zgtU5R1ngdhcsMmCSwAH1oTLVJ%20ck8BBLzgBqnTfT0tNXyo9raNdMkaIDGzNzaGBRBSTZIhdDh%20B9fMlrq%208aB9HgpFkVUnJ6WU4DdJrYCOlg%20FW6V1EJKBGH7MjHsQ1UYC9XaFrwCALo8W7jqgYrXvelAyKIdIXuBD7NsIZHODOzrurWjQNokIgUZkDgNwAAwAEhoeG3sRiR6kJmB2BJmhMZFMj6mkUnyah5nCZChhGG9V0WCc%20a3hIFg9WIbhwZQSHKfEbmmD5xCnJGlBtN011EMeiWIYR6HIk18bA25%20pBHUKBSq8oWIAyyggA)

It will be helpful, if someone can even point me to the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: For this to be a [mre] you should probably define `RouteObject` in plaintext in the question itself, and ideally you would not add dependencies on third-party libraries to do so.  Could you [edit] to do that?

Comment: @jcalz Sure, will do that and will update you shortly! Thanks

Comment: @jcalz I have removed the dependency by creating my own interface. Please check the updated link.

Comment: Not just in a link, but plaintext in the question itself, as I mentioned before.

Comment: So `id` and `path` are optional? I assume if some node in the tree has no `path` then there's no point in recursing down, right?

Comment: Sorry, just updated the question text. Actually there is a point in continue recursing down even when there is no `path` or `id`. My code is not tested against that possibility, but , we should recurse down by skipping that node, because react-router behaves similar to that.

Comment: I don't get it, how would you join the path if one of them is blank?  Please ether provide a [mre] that demonstrates the use cases you care about, or remove the requirement and deal with it yourself offline.

Comment: It will take some time for me to implement the minimal reproducible example, so choose to deal with it offline.

Comment: Okay, so then please [edit] the question so that `id` and `path` are required properties, and let me know if [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKPPZw) meets your needs or not.  If it meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz The approach you used looks excellent. Please post your solution as answer, I will try to find more on how to deal with empty id and path offline now. Thank you very much for a fast and precise solution.

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: @jcalz your solution works fine in TS Playground, but not in my VSCode editor. I am using Typescript 4.9.5 in my VSCode and in my project. I tried to use same version on TS Playground. It works there but not in my local system. Do I need to turn on any additional settings in tsconfig? Error message is a bit long to display here, so I will update the question with it and will notify you.

Comment: sorry, I just read your answer and can see that you are using `children?: readonly RouteObject[]`. I actually never knew that I had to make it readonly for the solution to work. I just changed in my IDE and now it works fine. Thank you for the great answer. I will mark it as answer.

Comment: It's possible for it to be made to work without `readonly` but then you can't use `as const` directly and it would be a whole big digression.

Comment: Nope, no changes required as the answer fits my needs. Thanks again for the great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to operate under the assumption that `id` and `path` are required, and that you don't actually require `children` to be a mutable array type, so my definition of `RouteObject` is

```
type RouteObject = {
  id: string,
  path: string,
  children?: readonly RouteObject[]
};
```

(Note that [`readonly` arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type) are *less* restrictive than mutable ones, even though the name might imply otherwise.)

---

Also, in order for this to possibly work, you need the compiler to keep track of the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of all the nested `id` and `path` properties of your route objects.  If you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `routeObjects` like this:

```
const routeObjects: RouteObject[] = [ ⋯ ];
```

then you are telling the compiler to throw away any more specific information from that initializing array literal.  Even if you leave off the annotation like:

```
const routeObjects = [ ⋯ ];
```

the compiler will not infer anything more specific than `string` for the nested `id` and `path` properties, since usually people don't want such narrow inference.  Since we *do* want narrow inference, we should tell the compiler that via a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const routeObjects = [ ⋯ ] as const;
```

If you look at the type of `routeObjects` now, you'll see that the compiler infers a quite specific [`readonly` tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types):

```
/* const routeObjects: readonly [{
    readonly id: "root";
    readonly path: "/";
    readonly children: readonly [{
        readonly id: "auth";
        readonly path: "auth";
        readonly children: readonly [⋯] // omitted for brevity
    }, {⋯}]; // omitted for brevity
}] */
```

and this is why I widened `children` to allow `readonly RouteObject[]` above; otherwise this would fail to be a `RouteObject[]` and we'd have to play more games to get it to be accepted.

Anyway, now we're finally at a place where we can *start* to give strong typings.

---

I'm not going to touch the implementation of `createRoutes()` much at all, since there's no way the compiler will ever be able to verify that it conforms to what will turn out to be quite a complex call signature.  Instead I'll just hide the implementation behind a single-call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), or the equivalent. For the rest of the answer I'm not going to worry about implementation of the function and just look at the call signature:

```
declare function createRoutes<T extends readonly RouteObject[]>(
  routeObjects: T
): Routes<T>;
```

So, `createRoutes()` will be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `T` of `routeObjects` which has been [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `readonly RouteObject[]`.  And it returns an object of type `Routes<T>`, which we will define as... oh boy here it comes:

```
type Routes<T extends readonly RouteObject[]> = {
  [I in keyof T]: (x:
    Record<T[I]['id'], T[I]['path']> & (
      T[I] extends {
        path: infer P extends string,
        children: infer R extends readonly RouteObject[]
      } ? { [K in keyof Routes<R>]:
        `${P extends `${infer PR}/` ? PR : P}/${Extract<Routes<R>[K], string>}`
      } : {}
    )
  ) => void
}[number] extends (x: infer U) => void ?
  { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never;
```

That's quite complex, but possibly not any more complex than the type manipulation you want to see.  It's a recursive type, where `Routes<T>` is defined in terms of `Routes<R>` for each `R` corresponding to the `children` property the elements of `T`.

Let's break down what `Routes<T>` does:

- It walks through each element (at index `I`) of the tuple type `T` and makes an object type whose only key is the `id` property and whose value at that key is the `path` property.  That's what `Record<T[I]['id'], T[I]['path']>` (using [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)) means.  So for the first (and only) element of `routeObjects` it makes the equivalent of `{root: "/"}`.
- If the element has a `children` property `R` (which is checked via [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) using `T[I] extends { ⋯ children: infer R ⋯ } ? ⋯` ), it also recursively evaluates the object type `Routes<R>`. So for that element it makes something like `{ auth: "auth"; login: "auth/login"; vishal: "auth/login/vishal"; register: "auth/register"; ⋯ }`
- It takes `Routes<R>` and [maps it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to a version where we prepend the current `path` property to it with a slash (unless it ends in a slash in which case we suppress the slash; this is a fiddly bit you might want to tweak depending on the implementation).  That's what `` { [K in keyof Routes<R>]: `${P extends `${infer PR}/` ? PR : P}/${Extract<Routes<R>[K], string>}`} `` means.   So for that element it makes something like `{ auth: "/auth"; login: "/auth/login"; vishal: "/auth/login/vishal"; register: "/auth/register"; ⋯ }`
- It takes both of these object types and [intersects](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) them together.  (Note that if the element has no `children` then we just intersect the empty object type `{}` instead).
- Now what we do is collect all these individual pieces and intersect them all together to get one huge intersection `U`.  This is done via the same technique as `TupleToIntersection<T>` as described in the answer to ["TypeScript merge generic array"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74202280/2887218); we put each piece in a [contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) type position, get a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of those, and then infer a single type from that position, which results in a huge intersection.  That's what `{ [I in keyof T]: (x: ⋯ ) => void}[number] extends (x: infer U) => void ? ⋯ : never` does.  So if walking through the array gives us something like `[{a: "b"} & {c: "b/d"}, {e: "f"} & {g: "f/h"}]`, then it is converted into the single intersection `{a: "b"} & {c: "b/d"} & {e: "f"} & {g: "f/h"}`
- Finally because a huge intersection is ugly, we collect them into a single object type by doing a simple identity mapped type over `U`; that's what `{ [K in keyof U]: U[K] }` does.  So if `U` is `{a: "b"} & {c: "b/d"} & {e: "f"} & {g: "f/h"}`, then the output is `{a: "b"; c: "b/d"; e: "f"; g: "f/h"}`.

Whew, that was rough.  Okay, let's test it:

```
const routes = createRoutes(routeObjects);
/* const routes: {
    root: "/";
    auth: "/auth";
    login: "/auth/login";
    vishal: "/auth/login/vishal";
    register: "/auth/register";
    resetPassword: "/auth/reset-password";
    resendConfirmation: "/auth/resend-confirmation";
    playground: "/playground";
    playgroundFormControls: "/playground/form-controls";
} */
```

Hooray, that's exactly what you wanted to see.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2BA8gIwFYQMbCgXigG8AoKKASwBMAuKAZ2ACcKA7AcwBoyowBDYAAs6jFh27lsgigBsqTCKwD8dBXypxWMkLETJ0WXAG0AuiQC+AbhIlsmxlCZ7UmHMHoEoRnqXLlqdADkTnDAgRJ+-EJBAPThPJLScgqsdN5+fr4ZfgFQgXxIgvHZkQLCeQVCxSVQUrLyimkJNVk1ObR5MnDsbNVt5FHlgV09rH39dcmNXs39xLNzlB2BAG4U9IJ8MuOLvGVBaxtbO-3mEXMm5zVnCxmt-bnBED2MEEwnJYNBCi-I71clG5ze5tR4KegQYAABT49HoAHc4EwqB9sl88uDIQBafhwxHI1HkIH9EE1MEQCGsKgAYU0ADMKEwALYCCiaQmlaIYimKKhYuysBnM1nsgHZYklS4LCWZW5LIJgGR8EDsJwIKmo9GBRXK1WIDVixL1FJNYFyjKPHUqtVUgBiSKZtNYzDgMnoHIG+zydId-M0LrdHJlGSlgKuoagNxMUFhtXswGsJBiACo46wHGr9K5cPRVBB1JptF57moNFodLkAEQhYCV6wZUuFnToysxOvNRvl2pJBqpRz5stFoyk8idotVyqCdttMfNr2VyfTmqz7vG6YroyAe6IzBkzsRN+YTNZD1BkzEbKBILokBSADwAFSgEAAHsgqR4V-AbwY3KYAHyeFkRgAJKUKwUAANYQCAcB0lA94mHQAAUz40M0MA4EiVAPiBJhGIE1CBJc8G4fhgxEQBABkUBIQs964U+r68h4I57FybB0m8UBQoxb5UB4ohsFwcqTL2dAcVxMC8cx-YFl2X5ZoYwCmNKUBKMQXgANJgZB0GwdeyD0LeMB-ohcoAAYACREDxL58R4VlEBJTDcTA5gxOZamuVAdBQu51kAKKvkwfC4MZzhGSZRiacRgkcH+5jmapdBEOYzQAJQ8OlBAASscDUBYRisAgTJoG80Z2TJKHiYKXEAKrZfguX5VQak+FpOlQTBcF1YhUB1dF0bmD5UCsBAKxvImdLqrgbLgdgajIApd6PpV76yYOOjLT+xgmH+SGZi4Sm5vB6V0MtRn3n+1jTaws2aLUi0QBdB3ODt7h5nJRbbdmynEfwKTQmUniBOEjgRedmHIrecVcAwzBCQBhCpdlWQ+i5SEyJCGnUJwbHlAoSrABQE0wkIeOiSkkZQPph3vfQqPNFjeA1hhRMkxAZOCAQCyE6ypPA-gQt5HEUAAD5i3sgNcwQwuBKL6mOQDihA0I5jWXzxMC2rnl0ErfDS2U-lEJrHNc4l9Y5HBSHUNlh30EY1DRoQrMQOz2uCJb-jW5TijZUhC35ktEUxh4fCsCA6UBz2KR4677uc2UccRelltpaOkIIEw4H28eNgChmIeEIHAjPRFr3fr9DPWCmaaFzeJ0lnAoR0K2S7kJOrcxIuXtQCMbBd5OMT96w7dQIcmwyIPhTD90bAxBPWxjz86x-NPQgxCvrxMMvPJA3iWHr4Im97zisIIlhu+UjS9KMiyxOaEfJ-X36gp3yKo+91aerqh0rbfzaKgY8AH6ioPaZkToAwnX-kqa0oCYjoyZK-KB7ZhpnlsPYV0EAAB0IwK6GUykAA)